# Rotating Images

Tags: transforms, compositing-nodes, image

My issue is I do not know how to rotate an image. The picture is a JPEG and Blender keeps loading them improperly, so I need to correct with rotation. How do I do that?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

To rotate an image in the *Compositor*, you can either use the [**Transform**](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/compositing/types/transform/transform.html) node (<kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>A</kbd> *> Transform > Transform*) or the [**Rotate**](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/compositing/types/transform/rotate.html) node (<kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>A</kbd> *> Transform > Rotate*):

[image]
*Marcie rotated 90° (click to enlarge)*

In some cases a 'backplate' is required to introduce a background color or  crop the image. To mix both images you can use a [**Mix**](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/compositing/types/color/mix/mix_color.html) node and enable *Include Alpha of second input* by clicking on icon right beside the 'blend-type' of that node. Create another [**Image**](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/compositing/types/input/image.html) node or create an 'empty plate' via [**Mask**](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/compositing/types/input/mask.html) node. Plug the 'foreground' into the lower socket and the 'background' into the upper one:

[image]
*Marcie rotated 45° (click to enlarge)*

**Note:** Always make sure that the *Render Dimensions* are set correctly.

[image]