# Need workflow to render color-corrected video

Tags: rendering, video

So I got the video file imported into Blender via the Node Editor. I already played with the nodes to my satisfaction. I need to rotated it still, as it was shot with a phone (vertical). After that I need to output it to a video file format, like MPEG.
Will I need to do it in 2 parts?: 1.Output it with the colors corrected, then 2. Rotate it?
Or can these 2 things be done before outputting?

Comment: related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/45952/rotating-images/45953#45953

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it before outputting. Add a "Rotate" node (from "Distort -> Rotate") and change the degree by 90 degrees.

[image: Rotate Node]

After that go to your render settings and swap the X and Y values.

[image: Render resolution]