# Why my composite nodes are not working?

Tags: compositing-nodes

[image]I know I could be feeding a movie file to the Compositor, but then it would take 2 steps (1. render video with color correction from VSE, 2. feed it to the Compositor to rotate it -90 degrees and render the result.)

So I am trying to feed the Compositor with a render layer instead. But it's not working. I have both Compositor and Sequencer check-marked in Post Processing in the Render tab.
Is there something wrong with the nodes, or something else?

Comment: Could you show a screenshot of your node setup?

Comment: You need an addon do achieve this. It's easier to use intermediate image file.

Comment: Does this help: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/45952/rotating-images ?